# How i can use autocomplete with google places api

Tags: ios7, autocomplete

i want to use autocompletion for google place. can any one tell stapes to use autocomplete in google place for iOS7 .

Comment: isnt this the perfect thinga =? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=de

Comment: No i want to use autocomplete with ios7

Comment: and ios7 doesnt support javascript or whats your statement ?

Comment: i need to know the stapes involved in google places autocomplete api integration with ios7 or any sample code?